How can I move (attach) one object to another exactly without doing it manually?
I have two hexagons, I want the side of one to exactly coincide with the side of the second. Doing it with your hands is crooked and inconvenient. Is it possible to somehow move one to the other in a blender by selecting the sides of the connection. I can't find on the Internet how to do this, some of the suggestions are connections by stretching one to another, but I need to save the shapes of all the polygons. An example of what I want to achieve is manually applied
enter image description here
I will be very grateful for your help

Ask this on Blender StackExchange site as the question is not about programming
